# Como atualizar TextView a partir da AsyncTask?

Tags: android, async

Vi neste exemplo, atualizando o campo `TextView` de dentro da `AsyncTask` mas não consigo repetir isso no meu código, e ao que me parece isso nem é possível ou é?

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    // updating UI from Background Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    // product with this pid found
                    // Edit Text
                    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                    txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                    txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                    // display product data in EditText
                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                }else{
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

Meu Código!

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {      
        public void run() {
                List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", pid));   

                //Conexao
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Extras.urlListarProdutosID(), "POST", param);

                  try {
                        int success = json.getInt("sucesso");
                        if (success == 1) {
                            JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray("produto");
                            JSONObject produto = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);                      

                            nome.setText(produto.getString("nome"));                     

                        }                                       

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A documentação oficial do `Android` está [aqui](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> Task Assíncrona é definida como uma computação que roda em uma Thread de Background e que o resultado é publicado na Thread da Interface (UI Thread). No Android temos 3 tipos genericos, chamados Params,Progress e Result, e 4 passos chamados onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate e onPostExecute.

**Tipos genéricos de AsyncTask**

- Params   - Tipo do parametro enviado para a task
- Progress - Tipo do parametro da unidade de progresso que vai ser utilizada na task
- Result   - Tipo do resultado da task

Nem todos os parametros são utilizados na Task, para ignorar um parametro utilize a classe `Void`

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

**Quatro passos**

Quando a task é executada ela passa por 4 passos:

- onPreExecute() - Invocado na UI Thread antes da execução.
- doInBackground(Params...) - Invocado depois de onPreExecute() e executa em uma Thread separada.
- onProgressUpdate(Progress...), Invocado na UI Thread depois que for chamado o método publishProgress(Progress...) dentro do doInBackground(...)
- onPostExecute(Result), Invocado depois que termina doInBackground(...)

**Para um XML assim:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Task"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Você poderia fazer a AsyncTask para atualizar assim:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(getOnClickButton());
        Log.d("test","onCreate");
    }

    private View.OnClickListener getOnClickButton() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("test","onClick");
                startTask();
            }
        };
    }

    private void startTask() {
        new Task().execute();
    }
    private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String text;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Log.d("test","doInBackground");
            this.text = "Xubaduba";
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.d("test","onPostExecute");
            editText.setText(this.text);
        }
    }
}
```

**No Log você iria obter algo do tipo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela sua explicação!

Comment: So marcar como ok a resposta Marcelo. :)

Answer (score 3):

Quando um `AsyncTask` é executado passa por 4 fazes:

`onPreExecute()` - É executado no UI thread e antes do task ser executado.

`doInBackground(Params...)` - É executado no `background thread` logo após `onPreExecute()`

`onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` - É executado no UI thread quando é invocado por `publishProgress(Progress...)`, é aqui que você deve actualizar a `View` durante o decorrer do `AsyncTask`.

`onPostExecute(Result)` - É executado no UI thread logo após o `AsyncTask` ter terminado. Aqui você também poder actualizar a `View`

Para uma explicação completa veja [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que você está tentando atualizar sua View dentro do método doInBackground() que é executado em outra thread e isso não é permitido.

Você pode atualizar sua View nos seguintes métodos da AsyncTask: publishProgress(), onPreExecute() e onPostExecute(). Para isso, dentro de algum desses métodos você adiciona o trecho abaixo:

```
EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);                      
nome.setText(produto.getString("nome"));
```

Ficando algo como:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    EditText nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);                      
    nome.setText(produto.getString("nome"));  
}
```

Simples!

Comment: Entendi é que eu vi daquele jeito, achei que fosse possível! Obrigrado